# AWS Elastic BeanStalk and VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Can we have two elastic beanstalk applications along with RDS database instances in one VPC.

What i am trying to do is the following:

1) EB App1: Web tier which hands web request

2) EB App2: Worker (application) Tier that performs the processing

3) RDS Db Instances: This is the database tier.

I want to put each of the above in one VPC and assign them within there separate VPC Security Groups in this VPC, hence controlling the flow of traffic between all the tiers.

Also, can i span these security groups into multiple availability zones.

Does beanstalk and VPC allow this above proposed design and is it a good design or am i overcomplicating stuff.

Thanks 
MHF

Answer (score 0):

> I want to put each of the above in one VPC and assign them within
>   there separate VPC Security Groups in this VPC, hence controlling the
>   flow of traffic between all the tiers.

Yes of course, that's exactly how a VPC works.

> Also, can i span these security groups into multiple availability
>   zones.

Security groups are VPC wide, they automatically span all availability zones. You would have to create Security Group rules that specify a specific subnet's IP range to narrow a security group to a specific availability zone.

> Does beanstalk and VPC allow this above proposed design and is it a
>   good design or am i overcomplicating stuff.

Yes, this is just a normal AWS VPC configuration. What you are proposing is the normal way to do this.